# Responsive heatmap.js on resize event handler

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, heatmap

First of all, I am using ReactJS and heatmap.js library.

The HTMLDivElement that is used as heatmap.js entry point should be responsive. At every window resize it adjusts based on the current window size.

However, the canvas created by the heatmap.js library object takes the initial dimensions of the div, so it's size remains the same.

**How could I make the children canvas responsive too?**

The heatmap.js **config** JSON is the following:

```
this.heatmap = Heatmap.create({
  container: this.image
});
```

The variable `this.image` is a reference to a **HTMLDivElement** that it is given dynamically the width and height attributes.

```
<div  style={{ width: `${width}px`, height:`${height}px`}} />
```

*If you're not familiar with JSX syntax, I could transform it into plain HTML/CSS/JS.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to just have the canvas set to 100% height and width, but contained inside a responsive `<div>`.

Comment: Maybe with a CSS selector the dynamically created canvas could be styled successfully.